# When is transform width in code not equal to the transform width in inspector?

Tags: unity, gui, debugging

I've come across a strange case in Unity's UI where the width of a RectTransform isn't the same as what is being reported. I have a transform which is 50 by 50 with no scaling, it is a root object of the canvas yet when I use the information that I get from the transform in code to draw from the bottom left edge of the transform to the top right it doesn't reach all the way!

[image]
[image]

```
Gizmos.color = Color.red;
Vector2 pos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
Gizmos.DrawLine(pos - transform.sizeDelta, pos + transform.sizeDelta);

Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];
transform.GetWorldCorners(corners);

Gizmos.color = Color.magenta;
Gizmos.DrawLine(corners[3], corners[0]);
Gizmos.DrawLine(corners[0], corners[1]);
Gizmos.DrawLine(corners[1], corners[2]);
Gizmos.DrawLine(corners[2], corners[3]);
```

The first section should draw a line from the bottom left to the top right according to what the transform reports are the width and height however they don't reach across the entire transform. Using [`GetWorldCorners`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.GetWorldCorners.html) the actual corners can be found and drawn around, with that data you can extract that **the actual width is 60** (150.2 - 30.2 = 120 / 2 = 60)!

Why? Is this a bug or an I missing something obvious here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because RectTransform.sizedelta only query the width and height values with no scaling applyed. You most likely have scaling from your canvas or a parent game object.
[image: UI Demo with rect scaled]
Tested in Unity 5.6.1f1